# Set title using macro and proc report

Tags: sas

I would like to create a macro to produce a report (proc report) for each datasets and include the title "Compulsion scale: Q6_#", but not sure how to add the title

```
%MACRO diff(var=);
%Let title = %var;
PROC REPORT DATA=table_&var.;
TITLE"CYBOCS COMPULSION SCALE: %var";
RUN;

%MEND diff;

OPTIONS MPRINT MLOGIC;
%diff(var=q6_1a);
%diff(var=q6_1b);
%diff(var=q6_2);
%diff(var=q6_3);
%diff(var=q6_4);
%diff(var=q6_5);
%diff(var=q6_6);
%diff(var=q6_7);
%diff(var=q6_date);
```

Comment: Why are you using `%var` which is not a macro name? Use `&var`. Also, please describe what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to a macro is a local macro variable.  To reference the value of a macro variable use `&` in front of its name.

```
%MACRO diff(var=);
PROC REPORT DATA=table_&var.;
TITLE "CYBOCS COMPULSION SCALE: &var";
RUN;
%MEND diff;
```